# Как верно отсортировать массив объектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив вида:

```
[
  {id:1, name:'Bob'},
  {id:2, name:'Josh'},
  {id:3, name:'Bob 1'},
  {id:4, name:'Josh 2'}
]
```

Нужно рабить name на отдельные слова `('Bob','1')`, и сравнить их с остальными элементами. В итоге должен получиться массив только с уникальными "словами" `['Bob','Josh','1','2']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Josh' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Bob 1' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Josh 2' }
];

let result = [...data.reduce((r, item) => {
  item.name.split(" ").forEach(part => r.add(part));
  return r;
}, new Set())];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Что такое new Set()?

Comment: @AlinaHomyakova https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: @AlinaHomyakova, https://learn.javascript.ru/map-set - хорошо все написано. Новая штука ( или почти новая) в современном стандарте

Comment: Оно берет уникальные, но не сортирует ("Josh 2", "Bob 1" — получится "Josh", "Bob", "2", "1"). Не понятно, аффтару это надо или нет)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, автору не надо, а вот аффтару - не знаю)